# how to store path in database and image in folder in asp.net with the help of javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to store a file i.e. image in folder and path in database in asp.net and I want to use java script. Will u help me how to get value of complete path of image in java script. I come to know that we cannot get the complete path due to security reason, is that true can we avoid this.

Comment: Actually which path you need? the path where file taken or file saved. Usually we don't need to know the path that user used to select the file.

Comment: If you are familiar with ajax and jQuery try the jQuery forms plugin. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ . It will help you to upload file asynchronously.

Comment: path of the file saved and later i want to bind that image in gridview by getting path from the database..

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to use [jQuery Forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form) for this purpose. We can use it in asp webforms like shown below.

HTML / ASPX Page

```
    <form id="myForm" action="fileupload.ashx" method="post"> 
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
        File: <input type="file" name="filetoupload" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
    </form>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
        // attach handler to form's submit event 
        $('#myForm').submit(function () {
            // submit the form 
            $(this).ajaxSubmit();
            // return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation 
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Pure HTML used in this example. If aspx webforms then, there will be only one form tag in a page.

Add a WebHandler (.ashx extension) to Website.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    HttpPostedFile MyFile=context.Request.Files["filetoupload"];
    if (MyFile.ContentLength > 0 && MyFile != null)
    {
        MyFile.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath("Path/On/Server"));
    }
    context.Response.Write("Saved Successfully");
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```